# ¿INCONVENIENTE AL MOSTRAR DATOS CON DATATABLE?

Tags: php, datatables

Reciban mi cordial saludo, estoy realizando un proyecto con datatable, mi tabla trae los registros de mi base de datsMysql (+3000 registros). El sistema funciona bien pero el inconveniente que presento es el siguiente:

Al iniciar sesión todos registros aparecen esto dura 4 segundos luego,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

vuelve a su estado de tabla, cual seria el inconveniente ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí les dejo mi código, espero puedan ayudarme a resolver este inconveniente

```
<body> 

          <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="row">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table  id="tablaPersonas" class="table display table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                        <thead class="text-center">

                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>NIVEL</th>
                                <th>PROY</th>
                                <th>RD</th>                         
                                <th>FECHA</th>
                                 <th>OFICINA</th>                               
                                <th>TIPO</th>
                                <th>DNI</th>
                                <th>APELLIDOS</th>
                                <th>NOMBRES</th>                       
                                <th>DOMICILIO</th>
                                <th>M-DEV.</th>
                                <th>M-INT.</th>
                                <th>FECHA RECEP.</th>
                                <th>RECEPCIONADO</th>                                
                                <th>ACCIONES</th>


                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            <?php                          
                            foreach($data as $dat) {                                  
                            ?>

                            <tr>

                                <td><?php echo $dat['id'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $dat['nivel'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $dat['nproyecto'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $dat['nrd'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $dat['fecha'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $dat['oficina'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $dat['tipo'] ?></td> 
                                <td><?php echo $dat['dni'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $dat['apellidos'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $dat['nombres'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $dat['domicilio'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $dat['devengado'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $dat['interes'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $dat['frecep'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $dat['recep'] ?></td>


                                <td></td>

                            </tr>

                            <?php

                                }

                            ?>                                

                        </tbody>     
                       </table> 
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
     </body>
```

Aqui una muestra de mi codigo, que trae los datos, como menciona el primer comentario

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       tablaPersonas = $("#tablaPersonas").DataTable({
           "columnDefs":[{
            "targets": -1,
            "data":null,
            "defaultContent": "<div class='text-center'><div class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-primary btnEditar'>Editar</button><button class='btn btn-danger btnBorrar'>Borrar</button></div></div>"  
           }],
  });
```

Comment: Cual es exactamente su problema?

Comment: Demora en cargar hasta llegar a la tabla. como dice el compañero de abajo "la cantidad de registros que está trayendo desde la base de datos es muy extensa, recuerda que todo este proceso de traer estos registros se realizan desde el lado del servidor, lo cual tarda un pequeño periodo de tiempo en procesar esta petición."

Comment: El error ocurre cuando conviertes la tabla en datatable después de cargar toda la página y como parametro "data":null, .

Answer (score 1):

saludos, bueno te cuento que puede estar pasando segun mi experiencia, la cantidad de registros que está trayendo desde la base de datos es muy extensa, recuerda que todo este proceso de traer estos registros se realizan desde el lado del servidor, lo cual tarda un pequeño periodo de tiempo en procesar esta petición. Por lo tanto, el data table que imagino lo estas inicializando dentro de un $(document).ready(); no se ejecuta hasta que la página está completamente cargada, asi que tienes que tener en cuenta la cantidad de registros que quieres traer hacia el lado del cliente para que esto no suceda y no se te presente este inconveniente.

Comment: Hola, acabo de editar y subir el código que mencionas, podrias decirme como pedir que cargue primero los 20 registros ? Se te agradece.

Comment: Como tal es dificil lo que quieres implementar, por que cargar esta cantidad de registros, tardará en procesar lapeticion, y que luego cargue el script de lado del cliente, llevará tiempo

Comment: Que me recomiendas ?

Comment: dada la cantidad de registros, que pagines con tu lenguaje de servidor (en tu caso PHP)